# Unbias estimator of the variance when individual observations differ in accuracy?

Tags: estimation, variance, sampling

**Experiment**

*Mother Seeds*

Let's say I have a seed. Let's call this seed , a "mother seed". I clone this seed many times, develop the organism and measure some phenotypic trait `X`. I then calculate the variance in `X` that is indicative how `developmentally noisy` is the seed of interest.

In this experiment, we have $M$ mother seeds.

*Mutants*

For each mother seed, I created $m$ other seeds that all differ from this mother seed by one mutation. I then clone each $m \cdot M$ mutants $n$ times to get $M \cdot m \cdot n$ seeds. I develop all these seeds and measure the trait `X`.

*Available data*

The experiment is performed through numerical simulations (there are no actual seeds) and therefore $M$, $m$ and $n$ are very big numbers. I could not store all the data and therefore I stored only the mean and standard deviation of `X` per mutant and the mean and standard deviation of `X` for the mother seeds. I therefore have $2 \cdot M \cdot m + 2 \cdot M = 2M(m+1)$ float values.

**What I would like to measure**

I am interested in measuring the mean square differences between the mean mutant `X` and the mean mother seed `X` for each mother seed.

We could call it $R_j$, where $M≥j≥1$ ($j$ is one of the $M$ mother seeds) and define it as:

$$R_j = \frac{1}{m}\sum_i^m (X_{j,i} - \bar X_j)^2$$

, where $X_{j,i}$ is the trait value `X` for the $i^{th}$ mutant of the $j^{th}$ mother seed and $\bar X_j$ is the mean trait value `X` for the $j^{th}$ mother seed.

I am not really satisfied with this definition though.

**The bias**

I could just use the above formula but my issue is that different mother seeds and different mutants are more or less `developmentally noisy`. If a mother seed and all its mutants are particularly developmentally noisy, then the $R_j$ will be higher than what it should be. Am I right?

**My thoughts on how to unbias the estimate**

Because variances are additive, I thought I could just subtract from $R_j$ (calculated as indicated above) the variance of the standard error associated with the variance among replicates averaged among mutants. In other words, I would calculate the unbiased $R_j$, called $uR_j$ such as

$$uR_j = R_j - \frac{\bar V_{j,i}}{n} $$

, where

$$\bar V_{j,i} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_k^n (X_{k,j,i} - \bar X_j)^2$$

, where $X_{k,j,i}$ is the trait value `X` for the $k^{th}$ replicate of the $j^{th}$ mutant of the $i^{th}$ mother seed.